# How to rewrite trigonometric functions for Fourier Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, fourier-series

So I have this piecewise function

\begin{align}
f(x) = 2, 0\leq x < \pi /2 \\
f(x) = -1, \pi/2\leq x < \pi
\end{align}

I want to expand this to a Fourier cosine series. Now I have found the coefficients

$a_0= \frac12$, and
$a_n = \frac6\pi  \frac 1n \sin(n\frac\pi2) \\$
by calculating the integrals. Now one issue I have is that I want to rewrite this nicely in the series. The series will be by my method

\begin{equation}
\frac12 + \frac 6\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1n\sin(\frac{\pi n} 2)cos(nx)
\end{equation}

but the book is showing this:

\begin{equation}
\frac12 + \frac 6\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)}(cos2n+1)x
\end{equation}

I really do not understand if I have done something wrong, but I really wonder how I transform this ?

Comment: Welcome. If $n=0,2,... \sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})=?$

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider your series.

Note that if n is even, sin($\frac{n\pi}{2}$)=0.
So we only need to consider the odd terms, just like the series in the book ("$2n+1$").

Also, if it is a number of the type $4k+1$, $sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}$)=1, if it's a number of the type $4k+3$, $sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}$)=-1.
Therefore we can rewrite your series as the one shown in the book.